# Only show products based on author user role on the frontend in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-roles

I have a vendor marketplace. I’d like to only display products that was created by a certain author user role (vendor).

To clarify, I’m not trying to change what user role sees what. Only trying to display products which are created by vendor.

I found [Hide products only show assigned products to certain user roles in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71320065/11987538) answer code

But what part of the code would I change to add the author user role? Any advice?

Comment: The current example is using product tags to filter products. So create tag named same as the role. To find all roles you can use global $wp_roles; $all_roles = $wp_roles->roles; and dump $all_roles to see them.

Answer (score 0):

To display only products based on user roles you can use the `woocommerce_product_query` action hook

In my answer I use the `get_users()` WordPress function, to retrieve a list of users matching certain criteria.

Once all IDs belonging to user roles have been obtained, we can use `author__in` to show posts associated with certain author(s)

So you get:

```php
// Change the shop query
function action_woocommerce_product_query( $q, $query ) {
    // NOT on backend
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    // Get IDs belonging to certain user roles - multiple roles can be added, separated by a comma
    $ids = get_users( array( 'role__in' => array( 'subscriber', 'administrator', 'vendor' ), 'fields' => 'ID' ) );
    
    // Show posts associated with certain author - use author id
    $q->set( 'author__in', $ids );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'action_woocommerce_product_query', 10, 2 );
```